# How to deselect all while using react-selectable-fast

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using [react-selectable-fast](https://github.com/valerybugakov/react-selectable-fast) in a drag and drop UI. I would like to programmatically deselect all at the completion of the drop event.

The [documentation](https://github.com/valerybugakov/react-selectable-fast) says it is possible:

> Using ref on SelectableGroup gives access to ref.clearSelection() method to unselect all items programmatically.

I've tried adding a ref to `SelectableGroup` and running ref.clearSelection(), but I get `ref.clearSelection is not a function`.

This isn't obvious to me and there doesn't appear to be any more documentation about the topic.

Can someone help me with a simple example showing how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you can apply a `ref` to the `SelectableGroup` object and programmatically call `clearSelection` on the ref to clear all selected entries.

Example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.selectionRef = createRef();
    this.items = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  }

  clearSelectionUsingRef = () => {
    if(this.selectionRef) {
      this.selectionRef.current.clearSelection();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.clearSelectionUsingRef}>Clear Selection using Ref</button>
        <SelectableGroup
          className="main"
          clickClassName="tick"
          enableDeselect
          tolerance={10}
          globalMouse={true}
          ref={this.selectionRef}
          allowClickWithoutSelected={false}
        >
          <main style={{ border: "0.1rem solid crimson" }}>
            {this.items.map((item) => (
              <Item item={item} />
            ))}
          </main>
        </SelectableGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `ref` can be accessed as `this.ref.current`. See more about [Refs in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Note that you can also use the component `DeselectAll` from the library for clearing the selection. But this can be used only within the `SelectionGroup` itself but the `ref` can be used outside it.

See a [live demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lfb6ax?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!